# regex phone with mask

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am trying to get a regex that will allow me to validate a phone with a mask.

The mask is () -

Example (333) 444-5555

Rules:

1. No preceding or trailing spaces
2. No spaces inside the parenthesis
3. 3 digits are expected inside the parenthesis
4. 1 space is expected after the closing parenthesis
5. Then 3 digits + a dash and then the remaining 4 digits

So far this is what I have but it allows phones without parenthesis:

```
^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$
```

Comment: Are `(333)-444-5555`, `(333) 444.5555`  valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per rule it should work

```
^\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}$
```

You can use `[0-9]` instead of `\d` as well.

`?` means zero and one time

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on it:

```
^((\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})(\s|-|\.))?\d{3}(\s|-|\.)?\d{4}$
```